# Error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-http, dart-http

I am learing about api's and http request in flutter and I got an error in making a get request
I got this error : Error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNU7X.png)

I got this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oy4Aw.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you say data[id] as String for example, that means: data[id] is null.

```
  factory Formule.fromMap(Map? data) {
    if (data == null) {
      return const Formule(
          id: '', title: '', prix: 0, nombreDePlace: 0, alertThreshold: 0, remainingPlaces: 0);
    }
    return Formule(
        id: data['id'] as String,
        title: data['title'] as String,
        prix: data['prix'] as double,
        nombreDePlace: data['nombreDePlace'] as int,
        alertThreshold: data['alertThreshold'] as int,
        remainingPlaces: data['remainingPlaces'] as int);
  }
```

2 solutions:

```
id: data['id'] as String?,
```

Or

```
id: data['id'] as String? ?? "",
```